# what does 'angle around' mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

The following is from "The Lewis Man" by Peter May.

> The Solas daycare centre was to be found on the northeastern outskirts
>   of Stornoway in Westview Terrace, a modern, single-storey building
>   **angled around** car parks front and back. It stood next door to the
>   council-run Dun Eisdean residential care home for the elderly,
>   surrounded by trees and neatly manicured lawns.

I've looked up the dictionary for "[angle](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/angle)" but still can't figure out "angled around." I know there are parking lots front and back of this single-storey building but their detailed arrangement is lost on me. Is it something to do with 'in a different direction'?

Comment: **angled around** is not a standard collocation, as JavaLatte indicates, but we can understand the phrase to mean that  the front and rear of the building had walls which formed a 90-degree or larger angle, between which a parking lot (or at least a corner of one) was situated. Seen from above, the building was shaped like a bow-tie.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: is it similar to partially "circled around" but with a sharper turn like a 90 degree?

Comment: In its structure, the phrase **angled around** is analogous to **circled around**.  But the meaning is rather different. The parking lot, or a corner of it, fits within the angle formed by the building's wings.  "partially circled around" approaches the meaning somewhat, except that the author is emphasizing the  building's angularity by coining that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angled%20around&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangled%20around%3B%2Cc0) shows that **angled around** is not common under any circumstances. Looking at individual instances, I have not found any that match this context.

If you had an L-shaped building with a car park occupying the rectangle bordered by the two sides of the L, it would be reasonable to say that the building was angled around the car park.

It is, however, hard to imagine how it could apply to car parks that are both at the front and the back. Even if you had a + shaped building, with car parks in each of the angles of the plus sign, this expression would not really describe the situation accurately.